# erro c3p0 - bad pool size config start 3 min 5. using 5 as start

Tags: java, spring

Olá, pessoal!
alguém pode me ajudar como resolver esse erro abaixo? tentei muita coisa e nada.

Erro:

```
12-Dec-2017 20:27:27.908 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1266 ms
12-Dec-2017 20:27:27.923 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/Head2Head] is completed
12-Dec-2017 20:27:39.276 INFO [MLog-Init-Reporter] com.mchange.v2.log.MLog. MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
12-Dec-2017 20:27:39.338 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry. Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
12-Dec-2017 20:27:39.448 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource. Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 5, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 1hge5tw9sldokl6qlaopl|1f977041, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hge5tw9sldokl6qlaopl|1f977041, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://*****************.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/nadalspringmvc?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 100, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 10, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> true, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
12-Dec-2017 20:27:39.465 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-2] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool. Bad pool size config, start 3 < min 10. Using 10 as start.
```

Código:

```
package br.com.head2head.dao;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

public class ConnectionPool {

    private static final String DB_USERNAME = "********";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "********";
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://********.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/********?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    private static final String DB_DRIVER_CLASS = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    private static ComboPooledDataSource dataSource;

    static {
        try {
            dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClass(DB_DRIVER_CLASS);

            dataSource.setJdbcUrl(DB_URL);
            dataSource.setUser(DB_USERNAME);
            dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

            dataSource.setMinPoolSize(100);
            dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
            dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(5);

        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não se trata diretamente de um erro, é apenas um alerta, aparentemente você não está setando o valor inicial para o dataSource.

Por padrão o valor inicial é 3, e conforme este trecho:

```
if ( start < min ){
    if ( logger.isLoggable( MLevel.WARNING ) )
        logger.log( MLevel.WARNING, "Bad pool size config, start " + start + " < min " + min + ". Using " + min + " as start." );
        start = min;
    }
}
```

Do `BasicResourcePool` disponível no [Git (linha 291)](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/master/src/java/com/mchange/v2/resourcepool/BasicResourcePool.java).

Para corrigir vc tem duas opções:

- 1 - Diminuir o min pool size para um valor menor que o initial (default=3)

  `dataSource.setMinPoolSize(2);`
- 2 - Ou aumentar o initial poolSize para um valor maior que o min

  `dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(101);`

Mais lembrando novamente, este é apenas um `warning`, e conforme o codigo a cima ele vai setar o valor inicial como valor minimo (`start = min;`) ao mostrar este warning.

Na prática sua aplicação vai continuar funcionando normalmente.

Outra coisa, se você estiver usando spring-boot vc pode configurar o pool do datasource pelo `application.yml`:

```
spring:  
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://********.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/********?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    username: ********
    password: ********
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
      enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        c3p0:
          acquire_increment: 5
          idle_test_period: 3000
          max_size: 1000
          max_statements: 300
          min_size: 100
          timeout: 500
          validate: false
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Brow-joe realmente não me atentei a isso, estava não explicito, conseguir retirar esse warning com a sua dica.

Answer (score 0):

É só um aviso (warning) de que o valor inicial do tamanho do pool (start) está menor que o tamanho mínimo do pool (start 3 < min 10), e portanto será usado 10 como valor inicial (using 10 as start).